# How to send email from Linux in a Windows Exchange network?

Tags: linux, email, exchange

I have an Ubuntu server sitting in a Windows network (that runs Exchange), and I want to send email from it.  The email will be To anyone, but only From one user.

How in the world do I do this?

We have made a user in Exchange, and I've tried using Nullmailer to connect to the Exchange server, but this is turning out to be rather difficult.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Maybe set up a mail server on my Ubuntu server?  But I suspect there are some settings like "Satellite" or "Proxy" or something fancy like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this: I didn't need to install postfix, because I'm only sending email not receiving.  So I uninstalled nullmailer (and postfix) and installed sendmail.

Then it all worked.

Without any configuring at all.

Well, that was simple.